# How to assign a value from php to my script variable to be used for flighplancoordinates of googlemap?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to get the output of my php and assign it to my variable in script. reason is because for every time I click a button I want to realod the content of my div id = "map" since the value of the flightplancoordinates would be changed I've tried doing something like

```
var flightplancoordinates = [<?php 
   echo "{lat: $latitude_data, lng: $longitude_data},";  
 ?>
 ];
```

but that would make my map unchangeable and static but I want it to be changeable, I know there is a lot to change but I dont have an idea where to start; the following is my script inside "test.php" and is pretty much the only thing inside my test.php except for the usual ones.

```
<div id="map">
   <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 18,
        center: {lat: 8.264670, lng: 124.263394},
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'


      }
     );

      var flightPlanCoordinates = [
       //where i want to assign the value
      ];
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
</div>
```

the following then would be an example of my desired php. "dbphp.php"

```
 <?php

$conn=pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=routing user=postgres password=password")
  or die("Can't connect to database".pg_last_error());

  if(isset($_POST['latitude'], $_POST['longitude'])){
     $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
     $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
     $result = pg_query($conn, "select * from shortpath($longitude, 
     $latitude)");
     while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "{lat: $latitude_data, lng: $longitude_data},";
  }
 }    
?>
```

the following is an example of the var flightplancoordinates with values from google api tutorials.

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
    ];
```

Comment: Don't build json yourself like that. Create a php array in your loop that looks like you want. Then after the loop, convert it into json using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Yeah i get the json_encode() part, but what do i do with my script specifically my var flightplancoordinates?

Comment: I'm not really what it is you're trying to do or where you're stuck. Are you asking how to update the data without reloading the page?

Comment: I've edited the question to show what my var flightplancoordinates should have.

Comment: and yes, im trying to update the data without reloading the whole page.
and just want to reload the content of my <div id="map">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass your data from php to javascript when you reload, you can use json_encode and echo it on a script that runs before your main script.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for the button on click and call your test.php to update the json value:

```
$(function () {
    $('#your_button').on('click', function () {
$.ajax({

        type:'POST'
        url:'test.php',                               //  (or whatever your url is)
        data:{data1:'your_data'},

        success:function(responsedata){
             flightPlanCoordinates = responsedata;
             //Also re initialize your map here
                   var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
               path: flightPlanCoordinates,
              geodesic: true,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2
              });

             flightPath.setMap(map);
        }
     })

}
});
```

I have not tested it. But it should be something similar.

Comment: thanks, something like this is what i was expecting. I'll try testing it now, and mark your answer if it works.

Comment: Also I guess you need to reinitialise your map in the success function to make it work. I have made an edit to my answer.

Comment: do i still need to do $("#map").load?

Comment: Yes whatever changes you do to the DOM you should do it in the ajax success function.